# Как выбрать admin dashboard для сайта?

Tags: html, компоненты

Для небольшого сервиса нужна простая админка для добавления и редактирования записей, тегов. Гугль выдает кучу подборок всяких admin dashboard, но как из них выбрать оптимальную малопонятно. если для веб-фреймворков можно найти рейтинг по популярности и востребованности, но тут ничего подобного не нахожу. Все описания таких админок в обзорах - это комбинация маркетинговых слов: удобная, хорошая, современная и т.д., которые не несут полезной информации.
ранее на одном проекте пробовали Gentelella, не понравилось что код любой странички перегружен кучей хтмл-конструкций. ожидал от таких панелей хоть какого-то компонентного подхода в эру великого React-a. Кто-то может подсказать есть ли подобные админки с использованием компонентного подхода, есть ли где-то хоть какое-то объективное сравнение характеристик подобных админок?

Comment: посмотри эту: https://github.com/ForestAdmin/lumber , оффициальынй сайт: http://www.forestadmin.com/lumber